# Detectron: no module named c2

Tags: caffe2

I am using Detectron from caffe2, but after running

```
python2 tests/test_spatial_narrow_as_op.py
```

I get the following error:

> no module named c2

I have checked the `lib/utils` and it has `c2.py`. I have also added the `Detectron/lib` folder to `~/.bashrc`.

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/issues/78

You have to include `detectron/lib` in your pythonpath.